# A way to have GCC poison only apply to the source and not command line?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a file that has been cleaned of all PLATFORM_X ifdefs and the aim is to keep it that way so it is platform independent.

So I added the following to the source code to encourage people not to add any more hacks with ifdef PLATFORM_X

```
#pragma GCC poison PLATFORM_X

#ifdef PLATFORM_X // compiler catches when a dev tries to add more hacky code
// bla bla 
#endif
```

however as the file itself is compiled along with every other file for this platform with -DPLATFORM_X, this triggers the warning.

```
./foo.c:3:20: error: poisoning existing macro "PLATFORM_X"
```

I really want the poison to only trigger additions in the source file. Is this possible?

(It's not ideal to modify the makefiles in this case as this really is a global define)

One alternative is just to #undef PLATFORM_X in a poison header file, but that way the code is just silently omitted instead of erroring out.

Ideas?

Comment: Doesn't `#ifdef PLATFORM_X, #undef PLATFORM_X, #endif, #pragma GCC posion PLATFORM_X` work you mean? I can't see why it wouldn't? Of course it wouldn't catch if Makefile defines it since we just undefined it. What's the difference of the above compared to when it's not defined at all?

Comment: Np, glad to help. Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

In files that are cleaned of `#ifdef PLATFORM_X`, you do not need `PLATFORM_X` to be defined, so write

```
/* PLATFORM_X configuration macro is deprecated; do not add new uses. */
#undef PLATFORM_X
#pragma GCC poison PLATFORM_X
```

after including any header files that may still make use of the macro.

Note that you *never* need to wrap `#undef` in `#ifdef`; `#undef` silently has no effect if applied to an identifier that is already not a macro.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_X
#undef PLATFORM_X
#endif
#pragma GCC poison PLATFORM_X
```

(Skip the `#ifdef` if you want to, but I just like to see things explicitly, matter of taste).

Of course it wouldn't catch if Makefile defines it since we just undefined it. Should be no difference between the above to when it's not defined at all.

Comment: I suppose this is more of an observation about me than the style, but when I see `#ifndef`-wrapped `#undef` my reaction is "you don't know how the language works if you think you need that."

Comment: I understand your point of view, however I work in several different languages throughout my work and they all behave differently. It's really easy even for the most experienced to misread or "halfway context switch" causing problems in situations like this. It's my opinion that it doesn't hurt at all, it's just very specific and explicitly shows your intention. (I reckon there are times when redundancy is stupid.) Quick example of an easy miss: Going from C to shell script, `function(){ time= newtime=60 ...}`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer unit tests for things like this. In your case, write a unit test that reads the .h file and search for `PLATFORM_`. If you find any such string, fail.